# Регулярка нахождения 2 одинаковых символов в строке

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Я пишу функцию, которая будет находить в строке символы, которые встречаются 2 и более раз, и если такие символы есть - заменяет каждый из них на ")", а если символ встретился в строке только один раз, то на "(". Уже придумал как сделать это другим путем, но хочу сделать регуляркой и str.replace - но не понимаю как.
Если пишите свой вариант - разжуйте пожалуйста регулярку на самые мелкие части, потому что просто списать не хочется, хочется понять.

вот такие тесты

```
"din"      =>  "((("
"recede"   =>  "()()()"
"Success"  =>  ")())())"
"(( @"     =>  "))(("
```

Comment: Эту задачу нельзя решить одним регулярным выражением.

Comment: ну может не одним, в целом просто есть ли такая возможность сделать это через поиск через регулярки и дальше уже как-то по другому?

Comment: Покажите, как вы это реализовали, может вам предложат более "элегантные" решения

Comment: я создавал объект, туда добавлял каждую букву как ключ, и значение было кол-во повторений, потом из этого объекта все значения больше 1 - заменял по соответствию этому ключу на ")" и оставшиеся на "("

Comment: Ну да, как то без двух циклов и справочника сложно обойтись

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы не составлять сложные выражения, воспользуйтесь [заменой через функцию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B2_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0):

```js
function ReplacingWithBrackets(text) {
  return text.toLowerCase().replace(/./g, (match, offset, string) => {
    return (string.split(match).length - 1 > 1) ? ')' : '(';
  });
};

console.log(ReplacingWithBrackets('din'));     //  (((
console.log(ReplacingWithBrackets('recede'));  //  ()()()
console.log(ReplacingWithBrackets('Success')); //  )())())
console.log(ReplacingWithBrackets('(( @'));    //  ))((
```

Логика работы такой замены проста:

- Последовательно перебираем все символы (выражение `/./g`);
- Передаём в функцию замены текущий найденный символ (*match*) и полную строку (*string*);
- Разделяем *string* на части, используя в качестве разделителя *match*;
- Если частей больше одной, то возвращаем нужную скобку для замены.

Comment: всё, увидел, спасибо, пойду читать

Comment: @AleksandrEgorov: дополнил ответ.